# CSS Div Duplicates itself

Tags: templates, html, duplicates

Hello I am working on [this](http://www.fenixflame.net/default.php) design, but there seems to be a problem with the "content-main-text". For some reason, it duplicates itself, (or at least thats what it looks like), one time it shows with 0 px padding, and the second time with 5 px padding (how it really should be displayed).
Here is the Template file code:

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = 'foro/';


$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link {
    color: #4d9547;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4D9547;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #d02c2c;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d02c2c;
}
a {
    font-size: 1em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #3D372B;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
body {
    background-color: #484238;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #4F493D;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#content-left {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_left.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left top;
    margin: 0px;
}
#content-right {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_right.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: right top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#header {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_top.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 3.5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
#header-left {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_top_left.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 44px;
}
#header-right {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_top_right.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#topnav {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/topnav_bg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #4F493D;
    border-right-color: #4F493D;
    border-left-color: #4F493D;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#Global {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #4F493D;
    background-color: #E0DACE;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/bg_content.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    width: 100%;
}
#page-header {
    clear: both;
    height: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    border: 2px solid #4F493D;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#navar-top {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#block_header {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block_top.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#block-content {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block_left.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left top;
}
#block-footer {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block_bottom.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
    height: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 24px;
}
#div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#content-right {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_right.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: right top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#topnav-search {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #4F493D;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #E2DCD0;
}
#footer {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/border_bottom.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    clear: both;
    height: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
#left-column {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_left.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid #484238;
}
#column-left-rightbg {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_right.gif);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#column-content {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#column-left {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
}
#column-left-quests {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#column-left-title-leftbg {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_left.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#column-left-title-rightbg {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_right.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
#column-left-title-center {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#Global #content-left #content-right #column-left #column-left-quests #column-left-title-leftbg #column-left-title-rightbg #column-left-title-rightbgTrue #column-left-title-center strong {
    text-align: center;
}
#column-left-title-mainbox {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1.5px solid #484238;
}
#column-left-quests {
    text-align: center;
}
#column-left-quests-title {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #484238;
    border-top-width: 2.5px;
    border-right-width: 2.5px;
    border-bottom-width: 2.5px;
    border-left-width: 2.5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#column-left-quests-content {
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2.5px;
    border-bottom-width: 2.5px;
    border-left-width: 2.5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    padding: 4px;
}
#column-left-HLM {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#column-left-HLM-title {
    background-color: #E2DCD0;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top-width: 2.5px;
    border-right-width: 2.5px;
    border-bottom-width: 2.5px;
    border-left-width: 2.5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#column-left-HLM-content {
    border: 2.5px solid #484238;
    padding: 3px;
}
#column-right {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 12%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#column-main {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_left.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
#column-main-rightbg {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top_right.gif);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 12px;
}
#column-main-content {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/block2_top.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 11px;
}
#column-main-text {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    padding: 5px;
}
#column-right-poll {
    border: 2px solid #484238;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#content-right-poll-title {
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#column-right-poll-content {
    padding: 2.5px;
}
#column-right-imagenes {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #484238;
}
#column-right-images-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#content-right-images-content {
    padding: 2px;
}
#column-right-herramientas {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #484238;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#column-right-herramientas-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
}
#column-right-herramientas-content {
    padding: 2px;
}
#column-right-videos {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #484238;
}
#column-right-videos-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(/Images/Backgrounds/Classic%20Template/Classic-Template-Column-Degradee.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #484238;
    border-right-color: #484238;
    border-bottom-color: #484238;
    border-left-color: #484238;
}
#column-right-videos-content {
    padding: 2px;
}
#page-banner {
    text-align: center;
}
.Image {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#new-copyright {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

-->
</style>
<meta name="Keywords" content="runescape, rs, ayuda, guias, español,  jagex, tutoriales, mapas, trucos, consejos, ayuda, items, quests, misiones, videos, herramientas, calculadores, bases de dato, monstruos, armas, armaduras, magia, java, online, juegos, multijugador, MMORPG, guilds, dragones, negocios, herbs, posiones, gemas, skills, atlas, guerreros, cuevas, dungeon, merchant, clanes, hispanos" />
<meta name="Description" content="Las mejores guias de runescape en español con mayor cantidad de detalle, faciles de seguir, sencillas pero completas y organizadas." />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>:: Fenix Flame, guias de RS en Espanol</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON"
       HREF="http://www.fenixflame.net/Images/FirePhoenix.ico">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Global">
  <div id="content-left">
    <div id="content-right">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="header-left">
          <div id="header-right">
            <div id="topnav">
              <div id="div">
                <div id="div">
                <?php               
                if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
{
echo '<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/faq.php"> FAQ</a> • ';
echo '<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/search.php"> Buscar</a> • ';
echo '<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/ucp.php?mode=register"> Buscar</a> • ';
echo '<a href="http://fenixflame.net/login.php?previousURL=' . $url . '"> Identificarse</a>';
}

else
{
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/ucp.php">Panel de control de usuario</a> • ';
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/ucp.php?i=pm&amp;folder=inbox"><strong>' . $user->data['user_unread_privmsg'] . '</strong> mensajes privados </a>• ';
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/search.php?search_id=egosearch">Buscar sus mensajes</a> •';
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/faq.php"> FAQ</a> •';
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/search.php"> Buscar</a> •';
    echo'<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/memberlist.php"> Usuarios</a> • ';
   echo '<a href= "http://www.fenixflame.net/logout.php"> Desconectarse [ '. $user->data['username'] .' ]</a>';
}
?>
</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="topnav-search">
            <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'es'});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('013088667146165371013:-bdq_dp2ewk');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.SMALL_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
  }, true);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/espresso.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/espresso.css" type="text/css" /> 
</div>
          <p><br />
          </p>
</div>
</div>
      <div id="page-banner"><a href="../default.html"><img src="../Images/Banners/Fenix-Flame-Evolution.png" alt="Fenix Flame Logo Image" border="0" title="Fenix Flame" /></a></div>
<div id="page-header"><a href="../default.php">Home</a> • <a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/">Foro</a> • <a href="../HTML/Todas las Guias.php">Guias</a> •<a href="http://foro.fenixflame.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12"> El Clan</a> •<a href="../HTML/Videos.php"> Videos</a> • <a href="../HTML/Contactarse.html">Contactarse</a>      </div>
      <div id="column-left">
        <div id="column-left-quests">
          <div id="column-left-quests-title">Quests</div>
          <div id="column-left-quests-content"><a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Cooks Assistant.php">Cooks Assistent</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Black Knights Fortress.php">Black Knights Fortress</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Demon Slayer.php">Demon Slayer</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Dorics Quest.php">Dorics Quest</a> <br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Dragon Slayer.php">Dragon Slayer</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Ernest the Chicken.php">Ernest the Chicken</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Goblin Diplomacy.php">Goblin Diplomacy</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Imp Catcher.php">Imp Catcher</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Knight's Sword.php">Knights Sword</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Unstable foundations.php">Unstable Foundations</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Pirates Treassure.php">Pirates Treassure</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Prince-Ali-Rescue.php">Prince Ali Rescue</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Restless Ghost.php">Restless Ghost</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Romeo y Julieta.php">Romeo y Julieta</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Rune Mysteries.php">Rune Mysteries</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Sheep Shearer.php">Sheep Shearer</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Shield-of-Arrav.php">Shield of Arrav</a><br />
            <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Vampire Slayer.php">Vampire Slayer</a><br />
          <a href="../HTML/Guias/Quests/Quests f2p/Witchs Potion.php">Witchs Potion</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="column-left-HLM">
          <div id="column-left-HLM-title">PvM</div>
          <div id="column-left-HLM-content"><span class="text"><a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Guias/High LM/King Black Dragon.php">King Black Dragon<br />
          </a><a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Guias/High LM/Chaos Elemental.php">Chaos Elemental</a><br />
          <a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Guias/High LM/Kalphite Queen.php">Kalphite Queen</a></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
<div id="column-right">
  <div id="column-right-poll">
    <div id="content-right-poll-title">Encuesta</div>
    <div id="column-right-poll-content"><strong>En tu opinión, ¿El actual diseño grafico del sitio es mejor o peor que el anterior?</strong><br />
Mejor porque es menos brillante<br />
Mejor<br />
Mejor pero le hacen falta retoques <br />
Igual de bueno
<br />
Peor<br />
Mucho Peor
<br />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="column-right-herramientas">
    <div id="column-right-herramientas-title">Herramientas</div>
     <div id="column-right-herramientas-content"><a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Herramientas y Utilidades/Calculators/Combat Calculator 1.0.html">Combat Calculator</a><br />
       <a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Herramientas y Utilidades/Calculators/Max Hit Calculator.html">Max Hit Calculator</a><br />
       <a href="HTML/Herramientas y Utilidades/Otros/Buscador-de-Items.html">Price Checker</a></div>
</div>
  <div id="column-right-videos">
    <div id="column-right-videos-title">Videos</div>
    <div id="column-right-videos-content"><a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Videos/Videos Guia.php">Videos Guia</a><br />
      <a href="New Classic Template/HTML/Videos/Videos de Entretenimiento.php">Videos Entretenimiento</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
      <div id="column-main">
        <div id="column-main-rightbg">
          <div id="column-main-content"><br />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="column-main-text">
         <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="MainTextRegion" -->
          <p>Hellooooo</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
      </div>
      <div id="new-copyright">This website and its contents are © 2009 - 2011 Fenix Flame. All Rights Reserved.<br />
      <a href="http://www.runescape.com/">RuneScape</a> ® is a trademark of Jagex Ltd. © 1999 - 2011 Andrew Gower.</div>
<div id="footer">"</div></div></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#content-main-text` is in your HTML code twice, one inside the other.

Comment: In my local copy of the source, it is not duplicated, hold on I'll post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a CSS problem; it's an templating/HTML problem. Have a look at these two lines:

```
<div id="column-main-text">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="MainTextRegion" -->
```

The problem is that `MainTextRegion` generates one of the `column-main-text` divs, so the first of those two lines is unnecessary. Just delete the first of those two lines (and its corresponding closing div) and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Just posted the template source code, as you can see the div is not duplicated in my local copy.